# How to scrolldown on page refresh using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with `height:400px` i have to add content inside it like right now i added just a div thats name `.content` now i want to scrolldown when my page refresh.

My Code:-

```js
    $(function() {
            if (window.performance) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.bottom').offset().top
                }, 'slow')
            };
        });
```

```css
   .scrollDiv {
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .content {
            height: 1500px;
        }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
     <div class="contianer">
        <div class="scrollDiv">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <p>This content should be appear on page refresh</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to scroll down? The whole page (document) or the `scrollDiv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do it like this, instead of just scrolling the `html, body`.

You should also scroll the `.scrollDiv` since this is the one with long content.

```js
    $(function() {
            if (window.performance) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
                }, 'slow')
                $('.scrollDiv').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.scrollDiv')[0].scrollHeight
                }, 'slow')
            };
        });
```

```css
   .scrollDiv {
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .content {
            height: 1500px;
        }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
     <div class="contianer">
        <div class="scrollDiv">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <p>This content should be appear on page refresh</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is correct.

The reason it's not working is because you set `scrollDiv` height to 300, but it's `content` is 1500;

change your `scrollDiv` to 1500, you will see it works.

Comment: i know after remove scrollDiv to 1500 it will be work but there will be unlimited content inside scrollDiv then that height may be increase thats why i have given scrollDiv height 1500, this is not solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
You are trying to scroll to the bottom of DIV.scrollDiv?

If yes, use this.

var objDiv = document.getElementById("scrollToBottom");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;





    var objDiv = document.getElementById("scrollToBottom");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
                    $(function() {
            if (window.performance) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.bottom').offset().top
                }, 'slow')
            };
        });
            
    .scrollDiv {
                height: 300px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            
            .content {
                height: 1500px;
            }
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
        <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"> 
   </script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
   </script>
       
         <div class="contianer">
            <div class="scrollDiv" id="scrollToBottom">
                <div class="content"></div>
                <p>This content should be appear on page refresh</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `max-height`alongwith `height` if content is expected to increase.

```js
$(function() {
            if (window.performance) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.bottom').offset().top
                }, 'slow')
            };
        });
```

```css
.scrollDiv {
            height: 300px;
            max-height:1500px;
           }
        
        .content {
            height:300px;
            max-height: 1500px;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
     <div class="contianer">
        <div class="scrollDiv">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <p>This content should be appear on page refresh</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
```